# How to integrate two halves of a symmetrical data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames, they are halves of the whole matrix:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- structure(list(`Cluster1-CONTROL` = c(568L, NA, NA), `Cluster1-DAY03` = c(
  578L,
  686L, NA
), `Cluster1-DAY06` = c(735L, 840L, 1059L)), row.names = c(
  "Cluster1-CONTROL",
  "Cluster1-DAY03", "Cluster1-DAY06"
), class = "data.frame")

df1
#>                  Cluster1-CONTROL Cluster1-DAY03 Cluster1-DAY06
#> Cluster1-CONTROL              568            578            735
#> Cluster1-DAY03                 NA            686            840
#> Cluster1-DAY06                 NA             NA           1059

df2 <- structure(list(`Cluster1-CONTROL` = c(568L, NA, NA), `Cluster1-DAY03` = c(
  639L,
  686L, NA
), `Cluster1-DAY06` = c(813L, 861L, 1059L)), row.names = c(
  "Cluster1-CONTROL",
  "Cluster1-DAY03", "Cluster1-DAY06"
), class = "data.frame")


df2
#>                  Cluster1-CONTROL Cluster1-DAY03 Cluster1-DAY06
#> Cluster1-CONTROL              568            639            813
#> Cluster1-DAY03                 NA            686            861
#> Cluster1-DAY06                 NA             NA           1059
```

What I want to do is to create this final data frame where the `df2` will be flipped and put at the bottom of `df1`:

```r
                 Cluster1-CONTROL Cluster1-DAY03 Cluster1-DAY06
Cluster1-CONTROL              568            578            735
Cluster1-DAY03                639            686            840
Cluster1-DAY06                813            861           1059
```

Comment: What role does `tidyverse` play in this? You're making a `data.frame` and talking about doing `matrix`-like operations on it. (The tidyverse packages do not play well with matrices.) I suggest that if you're doing matrix-like operations on your data, perhaps you should be using a `matrix` for it: it's faster and perhaps more intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are exactly symmetrical, you can first copy `df1` dataframe into another object, take upper triangular part of `df2` and put it on lower triangular part of the new object.

```
df3 <-df1
df3[lower.tri(df3)] <- df2[upper.tri(df2)]

df3
#                 Cluster1-CONTROL Cluster1-DAY03 Cluster1-DAY06
#Cluster1-CONTROL              568            578            735
#Cluster1-DAY03                639            686            840
#Cluster1-DAY06                813            861           1059
```